# Filename length limits on linux?

Tags: linux, limits

Are there any filename or path length limits on Linux?

Comment: See: https://arvimal.blog/2016/07/21/max-file-name-length-in-an-ext4-file-system/

Comment: The above article is now at https://arvimal.github.io/posts/2016/07/2016-07-21-max-file-name-length-in-an-ext4-file-system/

Comment: https://arvimal.wordpress.com/2016/07/21/max-file-name-length-in-an-ext4-file-system/ new link to that.

Answer (score 183, accepted):

See the [Wikipedia page about file systems comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Limits), especially in column **Maximum filename length**.

Here are some *filename length limits* in popular file systems:

```
BTRFS   255 bytes
exFAT   255 UTF-16 characters
ext2    255 bytes
ext3    255 bytes
ext3cow 255 bytes
ext4    255 bytes
FAT32   8.3 (255 UCS-2 code units with VFAT LFNs)
NTFS    255 characters
XFS     255 bytes
```

Comment: answer is: limit is usually 255 chars (for those who are too lazy to click this link)

Comment: @rahmanisback that's right for filename limits, while path limits are usually defined by the OS, not FS (except for some strange FSes like iso or ntfs), and, on linux, are 4K

Comment: @nonchip thanks for clarification although the question was about filename length not paths.

Comment: Actually it was about both :D

Comment: 255 includes the extension. It's not like 8+3 in DOS.

Comment: Just pointing out: bytes != chars, especially if you use UTF-8. See [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/542450/is-the-ext3-filename-limited-to-255-symbols-or-255-bytes).

Comment: bytes == chars, but bytes != characters.  Using UTF-8 the proper terminology would be bytes == Coding Unit, bytes != Code Point.  FYI, the max characters for UTF-8 for 255, is 63-255 Code Points. A C/C++ char is 8 bits or 1 byte.

Comment: Also worth noting. In docker the maximum path length is 242

Comment: I'm shocked by these limits. Files per directory is unlimited, 4 billion files per volume, file sizes into the terabytes, volume sizes go to exabytes but we have a stupid limit of 255 bytes for file names?

Comment: It should also be mentioned that if you layer eCryptFS with filename encryption on top of these file systems (as installed in Ubuntu with encrypted home dir option) the effective maximum filename length will only be 143 characters. See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/32834/47938

Comment: This 255-bytes limit is actually pretty silly. There are very practical use cases for longer filenames, e.g. long course or book or paper titles along with by the list of author names. And there's software that breaks when it can't write the complete filename, e.g. `youtube-dl` when downloading the video of such a course.

Comment: @jih: The reasoning behind this: 1. A file name is an *identifier*. At length that long, the name is pretty much a file *itself*. Inner-platforms (like modern web browsers, as the prime example) are a software design anti-pattern for a reason. 2. If you want longer names, that’s what directories are there for. Structure them. Putting them all in one directory is hoarding. … The actual silliness is the 4096 byte limit on the total path. Which, in a worldwide network, can be reached by very reasonable means.

Comment: @DanDascalescu: That’s a bug in youtube-dl, and not the fault of the OS. At least in yt-dlp, you can limit the length of fields in the file name template (e.g. `$(name).150B`), or limit the total name, but that is a bad idea.

Answer (score 121):

I've read [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160612154907/http://fixunix.com/questions/14623-max-length-absolute-path-linux.html) that path length limit is in system headers. File name length limit is there too. On my system it's file:

```
  /usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.38-10/include/linux/limits.h
```

and C-lang defines:

```
  #define NAME_MAX         255    /* # chars in a file name */
  #define PATH_MAX        4096    /* # chars in a path name including nul */
```

and some more.

Comment: Sorry, but I'am new here an can't even comment, save vote. The previous answer (by sfp) should be upped, as it answers the question completely, while the others are partially off. Again, sorry for going besides the rules, but I can't be quiet when the best answer is at the bottom.

Comment: Just pointing out: bytes != chars, especially if you use UTF-8. See [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/542450/is-the-ext3-filename-limited-to-255-symbols-or-255-bytes).

Comment: @DavidBalažic: Although true, PATH_MAX under linux is just a guideline, most of the underlying file systems do not have a limitation.  This makes it hard to reference paths that greater than that size. I usually use "chunks" of PATH_MAX as a size.

Comment: @Rahly Where do you use "chunks"? In a program? In a filesystem driver?

Comment: either, but i'm talking about a program

Comment: Since some might not realize this: This means you can CHANGE the limit!
Edit the file, recompile everything that’s based on it. (Which would be pretty much everything, especially the kernel.) And then see if your system works as expected. (E.g. don’t change the file name length when the file system might not be able to cope since e.g. a length field is only one byte!) // On Gentoo Linux, a patch in `/etc/portage/patches/` followed by an `emerge -e @world` would do it.

Comment: For me it is under `/usr/src/linux-headers-6.1.0-12-common/include/uapi/linux/limits.h`

Answer (score 35):

<sup>I refer to other answers, please upvote them.</sup>

> Are there any filename or path length limits on Linux?

Yes, filename and pathname lengths are limited by :

- [file-system limits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Limits) as stated by [WerkkreW](https://serverfault.com/a/9548/106052) ;
- constants defined in `linux/limits.h` as stated by [sfp](https://serverfault.com/a/306726/106052).

To dynamically get these properties:

- Use functions [`pathconf` and `fpathconf`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Pathconf.html) as proposed by [Michael Aaron Safyan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6571596/938111)
- Create a filename (or pathname) longer and longer as explained by [dogbane](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6571693/938111)
- Use the command `getconf` as proposed by [tim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6582758/938111) that is also available on Linux:

  ```
  $ getconf NAME_MAX /mnt/sda2/
  255
  $ getconf PATH_MAX /mnt/sda3/
  4096
  ```

Comment: Here is a pathconf example in C: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16285623/how-to-get-the-to-get-path-to-the-current-file-pwd-in-linux-from-c/54155296#54155296

Answer (score 22):

And for the sake of saving time (and anchoring it to memory):

ext2, ext3, ext4, zfs: no pathname limits; 255 bytes filename limit.

Comment: Most programs are limited with absolute paths to `PATH_MAX = 4096`, though. That can be worked around if your program is able to use relative paths and you change your working directory first.

Comment: It's because various POSIX APIs such as `getcwd` and `realpath` (which you *can* reimplement in userspace code by reading the metadata for `.` and then changing to `..` and repeating until you hit the filesystem root) rely on `PATH_MAX`. ([Source](https://insanecoding.blogspot.com/2007/11/pathmax-simply-isnt.html))

Comment: Yes, however, awfully lot of misc library code is prone to break if your code changes current directory at will. A well made code doesn't break but most of the existing code is not well made.

Answer (score 8):

Those are file system name lengths.  "linux" itself has some too.  For instance, from bits/stdio_lim.h:

```
# define FILENAME_MAX 4096
```

Comment: So since the extX filesystems have a lower filename limit than what's defined in the kernel, you wouldn't ever hit that limit, unless it also encompases pathnames, right?

Comment: that's what it looks like to me.  There's also PATH_MAX for the path, which is 4096, so it would be hit before the "unlimited" path size on the exts...  I'm not sure how the OS resolves its own internal restrictions and those of the FS, never had my arms in that deep.  interesting question though.

Comment: 4096 characters is a helluva path name.  I'm sure it could be raised with a recompile, but honestly, /why would you need pathnames that long?/

Comment: I'm not sure you would need it or not.  I view it more as a protection against malicious or negligent programs (I could easily see a script that behaves poorly and begins creating the same dir recursively.  Actually, I've made that script, but it was redirecting a web site, not creating dirs...).

Comment: @AveryPayne To add tags to files so they could be searched using a simple `locate`.

Comment: @HubertKario just curious, why not enable `user_xattr`, then store your tags as comments, retrieving files by doing `lsattr -R | grep 'mytag'`?  I guess you could stuff the tags into the file name but it seems like you would just clutter up your name space with absurdly long names.

Comment: @AveryPayne Your solution would be ideal, *if* there was *any* way to index or search extended attributes. From what I know only BeOS had indexes over xattrs and none of Linux FS do...

Comment: @HubertKario it would be pretty trivial to teach `locate` about extended attributes. For searching, the thing you put to the index does not need to be only the original filename.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen other problem is that xattrs are very error prone for handling (copying, moving, backing up). And most likely you wouldn't like `locate` to index all attributes, so then you need to handle non-standard configurations...

Comment: No need to put “linux” in quotes. It’s literally a kernel thing. So it’s true even on Android and SystemD. Not just GNU system that happens to use Linux.

Answer (score 4):

There is **no way** to determine the maximum length of paths on Linux in a portable way. On my system:

```
$ getconf PATH_MAX / 
4096
$ getconf _POSIX_PATH_MAX / 
4096
```

But I can easily create paths much longer than 4096 characters. Instead see `PATH_MAX` as a lower bound. You are guaranteed to be able to create paths this long, but you might also be able to create much longer ones.

Comment: A simple portable way to find the maximum length empirically is to write a program which creates longer and longer directory chains, and see where it fails. You won't know exactly why it fails (though you would hope for a suggestive human-readable error message) but you'll know how far you can safely go. Remember to check for both individual directory length, relative pathname length, and absolute pathname length.

Comment: Also, e.g. the Python `os.pathconf()` module will have some answers; if the Python port is any good, they should be reasonable.

Comment: You can't because some filesystems don't impose *any limits*. It would sooner fail with an out of memory error which any program would have a hard time recovering from.

Comment: This is the correct answer, except this is due to @BjörnLindqvist comment.  PATH_MAX is just a guideline, and 99% of files will probably be within that limit.

Answer (score 2):

You should always use **pathconf** or some function like this to get the runtime value about the specified items, as this [page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/limits.h.html) said that:

> It should be noted, however, that many of the listed limits are not invariant, and at runtime, the value of the limit may differ from those given in this header, for the following reasons:
>
> - The limit is pathname-dependent.
> - **The limit differs between the compile and runtime machines.**
>
> For these reasons, an application may use the fpathconf(), pathconf(), and sysconf() functions to determine the actual value of a limit at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

It's specified in the system *limits.h* header file.

Here is one of these files:

```
cat /usr/include/linux/limits.h

...
#define NAME_MAX         255    /* # chars in a file name */
#define PATH_MAX        4096    /* # chars in a path name including nul */
...
```

Here is where copies of this file are located and values they define:

```
find /usr | grep limits.h | xargs -I {} grep -H 'NAME_MAX' {}
```

Output:

```
...
/usr/include/linux/limits.h:#define NAME_MAX         255        /* # chars in a file name */
...
```