# cups fails to print files with very long paths

Tags: linux, cups

I got Debian 8 with CUPS 1.7.5 and HP LaserJet P2055D. Printing is OK, except that I can't print files, located on my network server with long nested paths. I.e. I can print file, located in \server\share\file.doc, but can't print same file located in \server\share\foler1\foler2\folerN\file.doc (around 200 characters combined). I can see error

> *"Returning IPP client-error-attributes-or-values-not-supported for Print-Job (ipp://localhost/printers/HP-LaserJet-P2055d-2) from localhost"*

in admin/log/error_log. Is there a way to fix this behavior (except to use shorter paths)?

Answer (score 0):

Not really. Filename (including path) limit for Linux  is determined by filesystem type in question: 255 is a usual limit.

[Filename length limits on linux?](https://serverfault.com/questions/9546/filename-length-limits-on-linux)